# How does one test whether a positive integer is semiperfect in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Wolfram Alpha allows to test whether a positive integer $n$ is abundant, deficient or perfect. However, I was not able to find a way to test whether $n$ is *semiperfect* (i.e., equal to the sum of all or some of its proper divisors).

How can I go about testing this property in Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: This may be a better fit for [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com). I don't know enough about Mathematica and WA to be certain, though. (Edit: I just checked, and WA questions are explicitly off-topic there. Maybe stack overflow?)